# How do I dynamically construct a string from a variable number of 'PopupMenu's in 'Manipulate'?

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, string-manipulation, gui-construction

I have a string with a variable length, determined by the value of a `SetterBar` and whose characters are determined by a corresponding number of `PopupMenu` controls, so that when the `SetterBar` value is `"+"` I get

[image]

and when it is `"-"` I get

[image]

and, or course, with the string changing dynamically as the `PopupMenu` controls values are changed. But I can't get either the dynamic update of the number of `PopupMenu`s or the dynamic update of the string to work with

```
Manipulate[
 With[{mk, n},
  n = If[ r4 == "+", 4, 3];
  StringJoin[mk[#] & /@ Range[n]]],
  Row[PopupMenu[Dynamic[mk[#]], CharacterRange["A", "Z"], ImageSize -> {45, 20}] & /@ Range[n]],
  {{r4, "-", "R4"}, {"+", "-"}, ControlType -> SetterBar, Appearance -> "Palette"}]
```

Ideally, also, each of the `PopupMenu`s should be `"A"` by default, and the string `"AAAA"`.

This seems like it should be simpler than I'm making it; but I think I'm doing multiple things wrong all at once.

How do I dynamically construct a string from a variable number of `PopupMenu`s in `Manipulate`?

---

FWIW, this is intended to recreate the behavior of something like

```
Manipulate[ 
 With[{spec = StringJoin[Table["A", {If[r4 == "-", 3, 4] - StringLength[start]}]] <> start},
  spec],
  {{start, "", "Start"}, InputField[Dynamic[start], String] &},
  {{r4, "-", "R4"}, {"+", "-"}, ControlType -> SetterBar, Appearance -> "Palette"}]
```

in environments (like Demonstrations) where `InputField` is prohibited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Manipulate version.

```
Manipulate[
 Row@string
 ,
 Column[{Dynamic[pop /@ Range[n] // Row, TrackedSymbols :> {n}], 
   SetterBar[
    Dynamic[x, 
     If[# === "+", n++; string = Join[string, {"a"}], n--; 
       string = Most@string] &], {"+", "-"}]}]
 ,
 
 {x, None},
 {n, None},
 {string, None}
 ,
 Initialization :> (
   pop[i_] := 
    With[{j = i}, 
     PopupMenu[Dynamic[string[[j]]], CharacterRange["a", "z"]]];
   string = ConstantArray["a", 4];
   n = 4;
   
   )
 ]
```

[image]

#### DynamicModule version.

Let me not use `Manipulate`, it is more handy with `DynamicModule` in more complex cases:

```
DynamicModule[{ pop, x, n = 4, string = ConstantArray["a", 4] },

 pop[i_] := With[{j = i}, 
   PopupMenu[Dynamic[string[[j]]], CharacterRange["a", "z"]]
   ];
 
 Panel@Column[{
    Dynamic[pop /@ Range[n] // Row, TrackedSymbols :> {n}],
    SetterBar[
     Dynamic[x, If[# === "+", n++; string = Join[string, {"a"}], 
                              n--; string = Most@string
        ] &], {"+", "-"}],
    Dynamic@Row@string
    }
   ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: It has to be `Manipulate`: see end of question.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius ok, see my edit.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius p.s. I love your profile comment :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it when I'm back at my desk.

Comment: I have a [follow up question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78398/37) about incorporating this into my `Manipulate`.